# How to remove padding in small screen using bootstrap 5.2 classes

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a container with a padding of 5 (p-5) applied to it.
However, I want the padding to be removed automatically when on a small screen without writing more CSS only using the bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center p-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block">
        <accordion />
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **.d-sm-none** class on the div containing the padding to hide it on small screens:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center p-5 d-sm-none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 d-none d-md-none d-lg-block">
      <accordion />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The **.d-sm-none** class will make the div hide on "small" sized screens or smaller, which means the 5px padding will be removed on these screens.
Best!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But the thing is that if there is a way of removing padding withough hiding the div?